# nested bson to flat bson in java or scala

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, bson

How do I convert a nested bson to flat bson in java or scala

*Input Bson*

```
{
  a: 10,
  b: {
    c: 20,
    d: {
      e: "a" 
    }
  }
}
```

*Output Bson*

```
{
  a: 10,
  b_c: 20,
  b_d_e: "a"
}
```

The problem i faced parsing was at

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": {}
    },
    "dateField": {
       "$date": {}
    }
}
```

where i wanted id as string and datefield as date

Comment: Don't you mean JSON? ... and what have you tried?

Comment: No BSONObject.
http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.5/org/bson/BSONObject.html.

BSONObject  has to map method used it to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener library.

```
new JsonFlattener(json).withSeparator('_').flatten()
```

Comment: This is good but i wanted something specific for BSON since BsonObject has it own storage structure.
Say :
{
}

Comment: {
   "_id": {
       "time": "",
       "machine":""
   },

}

when the bson object is parsed as json the id needs to represent in string